# Updating state always remain same value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, setstate

I have simple state like this

```
const [number, SetNumber] = React.useState<number>(0)
```

Then, i create an updater function in the first-render hooks like this

```
  const increaseNumber = () => {
    console.log(number);
    SetNumber(number + 1);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      increaseNumber();
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

From the console.log statement in `increaseNumber` function i got this output

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

Why the `number` state is not updating and always remain the same value?

Here's the full code

```
import * as React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [number, SetNumber] = React.useState<number>(0);

  const increaseNumber = () => {
    console.log(number);
    SetNumber(number + 1);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      increaseNumber();
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My expectation from the console.log output is like this

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things,

1. clear the interval on clean up of effect,
2. use functional updater of state

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [number, SetNumber] = useState(0);

  const increaseNumber = () => {
    SetNumber(prev=>prev+1);  // react takes care of updating number
  };

  console.log(number);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      increaseNumber();
    }, 1000);
    
    return ()=> {clearInterval(id)}   // as it continues to execute on unmount if you won't do
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};



ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Further explanation to that answer: The problem is that `number` with the initial value `0` gets inlined in the `increaseNumber` method. Therefore it's decoupled from the outside `number`.

Comment: to simplify, we can say that the "we lied to deps" saying this will only run once `[]` .... [here is the most complete guide on useEffect by Dan Abramov ](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: That's an interesting take! :D

Comment: Thank you sir, I just found out about the `functional updater of state` @KcH

Comment: @najimRizky no worries  please accept the answer if you found useful